# How do I convert the value of a UITextField to an NSNumber?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a small problem with iPhone SDK. I have 4 values in my xib, 4 `UITextField`s where I insert hostname, description, name and PORT.
The Port is an `NSNumber`. I must convert text (UITextField) into `NSNumber` but I don't know how. 
I tried the following:

```
NSNumber *temp = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithString:portTextField.text];
serverObj.port = temp;
```

but my app crashes. I don't have problems with `NSString` (description ecc.)

Answer (score 10):

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:textField.text];
[f release];
```

And that should get the job done.

Comment: Just be sure to hit the checkmark button to mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 6):

Just use the '**integerValue**' method of NSString, to get a '**NSInteger**'. Then you can create a NSNumber object from it.

```
serverObj.port = [ NSNumber numberWithInteger: [ portTextField.text integerValue ] ];
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no method for NSNumber objects called initWithString: (that's why your app crashes). You need to use NSNumberFormatter's method numberFromString: